# Digest authentication using Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, hash, xmlhttprequest, digest-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate with an API that uses Digest authentication.

I am sending a POST request to the server but the response returned is `HTTP 401 Denied`. This is the `WWW-Authenticate` challenge header from the server:

(backslashes included for formatting, not present in response header)

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Guard", domain="/", \ 
  nonce="MTMzOTA5Mjk1NTE2NDo0NzY2NjJiOTgyMjE1ZDc0OWU3NzM5MTkzMWNjNGQzNw==", \ 
  algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
```

Using parameters from this header I apply the digest authentication algorithm and build the challenge reply header:

```
const HA1 = MD5("login:Guard:mypassword");
const HA2 = MD5("POST:/");

const authHash = MD5(
  HA1 + ':' + unquotes(tokensObj["nonce"]) + ':' +
  tokensObj["nc"] + ':' + tokensObj["cnonce"] + ':' +
  unquotes(tokensObj["qop"]) + ':' + HA2
);

const challengeReply = 'Digest username:"login"' +
  ', realm=' + tokensObj["realm"] + ', nonce=' + tokensObj["nonce"] +
  ', uri=' + tokensObj["domain"] + ', algorithm=' + tokensObj["algorithm"] +
  ', response="' + authHash + '"' + ', qop=' + unquotes(tokensObj["qop"])  +
  ', nc=' + tokensObj["nc"] + ', cnonce="' + tokensObj["cnonce"] + '"';

xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", challengeReply);
```

The header sent to the server:

```
Authorization: Digest username:"login", realm="Guard", \
  nonce="7d0c753c2fb4cdc9480403547952f1", uri="/", algorithm=MD5, \
  response="e9d8ad8f04e42672f2c21d70257c1072", qop=auth, nc=00000001, \
  cnonce="bd5fd9b093dccaa1"
```

But this doesn't work, I still receive HTTP 401 Denied. The server digest authentication has been tested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake was specifying the `username` parameter with a colon, it should have been an equals sign (`username:"login"` vs `username="login"`):

```
Authorization: Digest username="login", realm="Guard", nonce="7d0c753c2fb4cdc9480403547952f1", uri="/", algorithm=MD5, response="e9d8ad8f04e42672f2c21d70257c1072", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="bd5fd9b093dccaa1"
```